# searching db for entries that don't exist

Tags: mysql, mariadb

this is a very stupid question for which i can't find a solution even if i'm sure there is one.

i have 3 tables.

client table

```
+----+------+-------+
| id | name | phone |
+----+------+-------+
```

each client has one or more locations.

location table.

```
+----+------+-------+---------+
| id | name | phone | address | 
+----+------+-------+---------+
```

each location has one of more services.

services table that has relation to both client table and location table.

```
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------+
| id | client_id | location_id | date | status |
+----+-----------+-------------+------+--------+
```

services table has 2 columns i need to filter from. column 1 is called date having datetime type. column 2 is status being int.

i need a list of client/location that don't have any services after a certain date whit the status being 0. i have tried many many queries, mostly stupid ones that i already figured out what was wrong whit them, i can't think of any more so i decided to try ask here.

this returns empty result but i know there are locations without services after that date

```
SELECT `id`,`name` FROM `location` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `location_id` FROM `services` WHERE `date` > '2022-09-01 00:00:00' AND `status` = 0 )
```

Comment: Can you create a dbfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/Elq3YNHE

fiddle works just fine, on my db server same query same structure returns empty result

Comment: If there's no service, how will you link the clients and locations? Or do you want two queries, one for clients and one for locations?

Comment: locations have relation to client, the issue is, that the query i did and works on fiddle don't work on my server. on my server it returns a empty result, didn't even think until now to try on another server, i always assumed my query was wrong not some db issue.  i will try to move the db on another server and hope it works

Comment: @Tavi I doubt moving the same schema and data to another server will make a difference. Are you *sure* there are matching rows?

Comment: the only thing i know is different is that some services point to "null" client_id and null location_id since those clients/locations were deleted long ago. the structures on diffle were just 1 row dumps from db. so its basically the same schema / foreign keys. just not real data

Comment: @Schwern THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! adding the location_id is not null condition for service table worked !!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do a left excluding join.

Select from clients. Do a left join on service, so you get all the client rows, but join only the services with the correct status and date.

Then filter for those rows without a service.

```
select c.id, c.name
from client c
left join services s 
  on c.id = s.client_id
 and s.status = 0
 and s.date > ?
where s.id is null
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/fn-OkR6A).